# Chrome Extension - to know if the content script has been injected?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way to know whether the content script has been injected successfully. I know we can use message passing. But is there a way other than that??

Comment: Do you inject it with `executeScript`?

Comment: You mean in the actual page, not on the background app right?

Comment: Yes using executescript...

Comment: @Sudakatux...no i mean on the background page..

Comment: So you're trying to figure out if your background page has already injected the script.  If it's truly a background page, then you can just create a global variable to keep track of that information.  Or do you actually have an event page?

Comment: @Teepeemm Sorry if the question is confusing...I didn't mean it like that.For eg: u can't inject script on chrome home page. I want to know if the script injected from background is successful

Comment: @NishanMiranda, see [chrome.tabs.executeScript with new browser tab not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32802122)

Comment: i'm not specific about new browser tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest way would be to use the optional callback to [`executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript).  End your content script with `'success';` on its own line.  Then your injection call would be:

```js
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, details, successStatus);
function successStatus(frameResults) {
  if ( frameResults[0] === 'success' ) {
    // successfully injected
  }
}
```

Comment: what do u mean by adding 'success'.

Comment: `frameResults` is an array, where each array element is the last evaluated expression in the content script in a frame.  So you want your content script to end with an expression that indicates it successfully loaded.  In this case, you can simply write `'success';` on its own line.  Chrome will evaluate that expression, and that will be the entry in the results array.

Comment: i added just as u said..but receiving null

Comment: thank you...got it..if i'm injecting via a file the last line must be json serializable

Answer (score 0):

Ok so say we are talking of the actual page and not the background extension.

First you must include the scrits in the page, here is how im doing this

```
var j = document.createElement('script');
j.src = chrome.extension.getURL('bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(j);

var k = document.createElement('script');
k.src = chrome.extension.getURL('bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js');
(document.head || document.documentElement).appendChild(k);
```

And then to check if it was loaded i have a an if condition

```
if( (/in/.test(document.readyState)) || (undefined === Backbone) ) {
    setTimeout('refresh(' + f + ')', 10);
  } else {
    f();
    console.log("Loaded Main Application");
```

So i ask if the state is ready and then check if the browser loaded my js.

Hope it helps

Comment: OP is using executeScript in a background/event page, so he's injecting differently than you.  (And don't use the eval form of `setTimeout`.  In this case, you should use `refresh.bind(undefined,f)`.)