# Modifying the built-in newtab page

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am not able to run my content script on the new tab page (where it is not assigned to any url).

I looked at various posts on the subject, ie, [Does content script have access to newtab page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948958/does-content-script-have-access-to-newtab-page)
and  [What is the URL of the google chrome new tab page and how to exclude it from manifest.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287333/what-is-the-url-of-the-google-chrome-new-tab-page-and-how-to-exclude-it-from-man)

which seem to suggest it is possible.

I enabled chrome://flags/#extensions-on-chrome-urls

I have:

```
"permissions": [
    "http://*/*", 
    "https://*/*",
    "chrome://*/*"
],
```

(also tried `"*://*/_/chrome/newtab*"`)

still no luck ... what am I missing ?

this answer [Can you access chrome:// pages from an extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19042857/can-you-access-chrome-pages-from-an-extension) mentsions "wildcards are not accepted". Is this true ? and if so how to specify the newtab page ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**The problem** is that Chrome 61 and newer [explicitly forbids](https://crrev.com/2978953002/) access to the contents of its built-in new tab page (NTP) via content scripts or any other API.

**The solution** is to create the entire replacement page as an html file in your extension and specify it in [chrome_url_overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

As for why, here's quoting [[source](https://crrev.com/2978953002#msg33)] rdevlin, one of the developers of chrome extensions API:

> There's a few reasons for this change.  One is to enforce policy,
> the other is for consistency.
>
> - We've had a [public policy](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/program_policies#extensions) for awhile now that states that modification of
>   the NTP through anything other than [Chrome URL overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override) isn't allowed (though
>   we didn't begin enforcing this policy in many cases until July 1st).  This is
>   merely bringing chrome code more inline with that same policy to help prevent
>   surprise if an extension is modifying the NTP and is taken down for policy
>   violations.
> - This is also for consistency, since we've actually treated scripts on the NTP
>   differently for years now, due to certain NTP magic.  For example, the URL seen
>   by the browser on the NTP is chrome://newtab, but the url in the renderer is
>   https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab.  Since chrome.tabs.executeScript checks
>   the URL in the browser, the script would be denied, even though content scripts
>   (checked in the renderer) would be allowed.  In theory, these permissions should
>   *not* be different.  Similarly odd, if the user is using the local ntp
>   (chrome-search://local-ntp/local-ntp.html), injection would already be
>   disallowed in both the renderer and the browser.  And, if we go waaaaay back,
>   the NTP used to be pure WebUI with an URL of chrome://newtab, where injections
>   were again disallowed.  Rather than have inconsistent behavior depending on the
>   type of script injection the extension uses, we want to have consistency
>   throughout the system.

P.S. Please don't edit the quoted text.