# executeScript "Cannot access contents of url" error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to inject some js file while tab open.So, on tab open i execute

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(function callback(tab, info) {   
 chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                         file: "executeScript.js"
      });
});
```

but some time it works ,some time i am getting

**Cannot access contents of url "https://www.google.com/_/chrome/newtab?rlz=1C1CHZL_enIN708IN708&ie=UTF-8". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.**
 error.
i have added * ://*/ * , in manifest file permission but no luck.

manifest.json

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["socket.io.js", "eventPage.js","jquery-3.1.0.min.js","jquery-confirm.min.js"],
        "persistent": false
},

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://*.amazon.com/*", "*://*.amazon.co.uk/*","*://*.amazon.ca/*"],
    "js": ["socket.io.js", "content.js", "jquery-3.1.0.min.js", "custom-socket.js","jquery-confirm.min.js"],
    "css": ["content.css","jquery-confirm.min.css"],
    "run_at" : "document_start",
    "all_frames" : true
}],

"permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "storage",
    "identity", 
    "identity.email",
]
```

Comment: show your manifest ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome content scripts and newtab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659294/chrome-content-scripts-and-newtab)

Comment: @w0xx0m, what is the solution?

Comment: @Jaromanda, i have updated manifest code

Comment: Why the spaces?

Comment: @Jaromanda, there is no space in real code..

Comment: well why have you put them in the code you posted here? kinda confusing don't you think

Comment: @Jaromanda now it's okay.