# Can I add javascript to chrome newtab instead of redirecting it?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know that we can override in-built webpages via

```
"chrome_url_overrides": {
        "newtab" : "newtub.html"
    },
```

and then modify `newtab.html` to whatever page I want.

My question is if I have a `new_tab.js`, Can I just run this script on `chrome://newtab` rather than creating `newtab.html` and then running `new_tab.js` on top of it.

I want to remove icon thumbnails(which I can do by making them hidden in `new_tab.js`) and keep the wallpapers.

Edit : One shitty workaround is zoom-out to 50%

Comment: Extensions can't modify the contents of the new tab page. You can only override it. This is intentional.

Comment: Can you explain the security reason behind this?
Like why allow Extensions to override contents of other sites and not new tab ?

Comment: The new tab is a browser UI page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome content scripts and newtab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45659294/chrome-content-scripts-and-newtab)