# How to overwrite CSS in Google homepage with Chrome?

Tags: css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I would like to overwrite CSS style in Google homepage.

- I'm able to do it with DevTools/Overrides but DevTools has to be always open.
- I checked some Chrome extensions and they work everywhere but not in this default tab (without url).
- There is an option in the right bottom corner to change the background but no way to define the entire CSS style.
- I remember something like this was possible, any CSS to any website on FF and Chrome, maybe they remove it.

Is there any way to change the CSS and make it permanent?

Any help will be really appreciate : )

Comment: Apparently by "Google homepage" you mean the default new tab page, in which case [you can't customize it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45659562) (well, technically there are ways to hack it but that's certainly fragile and won't be allowed in the web store). You can only provide your own page using [URL overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/override).

Comment: Yes, the default new tab page with the Google title, the seach bar and so on : ( Ok, so isn't possilbe nowdays. Thank so much wOxxOm!

Answer (score 0):

DevTools only makes client-side changes (changes that only **you** and **your device** can see). These changes do not affect the css that is sent to you over the internet. However, the changes you make in DevTools are erased every time the page is reloaded, and the default code from the server is restored. As a result, you can’t make permanent css changes to code from a server that you do not own; all client-side changes are temporary.